# PyMongo and toArray() method

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, document-oriented-db, database

I need to make some benchmarks on a small database (64MB) and I need to figure out what is the smartest way to fetch whole Mongo collection into python object with PyMongo? In JavaScript, there is toArray() method but I cannot find anything similar in python. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Have you tried?

```
result = list(db.collection.find())
```