# Get string array from Pymongo query

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I need to get an array with the values from the field 'colname'. I can't return a Cursor, just the array of values.

Is there a way to query this array without having to loop the Cursor? I feel this is a waste of processing resources.

Right now I'm doing this:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/')
headers = client['headers']

entomo = headers.entomo

entomo_data = entomo.find()
entomo_array = []
for data in entomo_data:
    entomo_array.append(data['colname'])
```

Then I return the `entomo_array`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PyMongo and toArray() method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8723613/pymongo-and-toarray-method)

Comment: @VinceBowdren this is not a valid duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the 'colname' field has distinct values or if you do not care about duplicate values you can use distinct function. For your example:

```
entomo_array = entomo.find().distinct('colname')
```

Comment: I'm not sure but I think this would consume more resources than just looping the array. Wouldn't it? But I guess the distinct's implementation has a O(n) complexity as it must use a Hashmap, just like looping.

Comment: About the execution time, I think that when you run distinct('colname') the command runs on mongodb server and then the result returns via one I/O but when you run a loop on cursor, generally I believe, the code will make more than one I/O. Finally, you can use the distinct command on collection level if you have not any filter. http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.distinct

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the [`.aggregate()`](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.aggregate) method by `$group`ing your documents by `None`

```
cursor = entomo.aggregate([
    {'$group': {
        '_id': None, 
        'data': {'$push': '$colname'}
    }}
])
```

From there, you simply consume the cursor using `next`.

```
entomo_array = next(cursor)['data']
```

But if 'colname' is unique within the collection, you can simply use the the [`distinct`](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.distinct) method.

```
entomo_array = entomo.distinct('colname')
```