# Efficiently convert field value to integer from mongo find() using python

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo, pymongo-2.x

Given mongo document like below, how to efficiently find all documents and return student_id field as integer?

```
 {
     "_id" : ObjectId("58dd757910d81946b8ff853a"),
     "student_id": "4169506398",
     "first_name": "steven",
     "last_name": "smith",
     "date_of_birth": "02-07-1988"
}
{
     "_id" : ObjectId("58dd757910d81946b8ff853b"),
     "student_id": "6902",
     "first_name": "michael",
     "last_name": "clarke",
     "date_of_birth": "05-30-1988"
}
```

**Expected result (in Json):**

```
{
     "student_id": 4169506398
}
{
     "student_id": 6902
}
```

I've 29000 records. Getting documents using db.find({}) and casting student_id to integer when looping might have performance issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this without client side processing or map reduce.

```
mylist = map(int, db.collection.distinct('student_id'))
```

which yields a list of `student_id` of type `int` in PY2 or iterator object in PY3

You can also use the `.aggregate()` method as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43086507/3100115) if "student_id" is not unique within the collection and you don't want to de-duplicate the result.